# chrome extension prob

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

My manifest code is

```
 {
  "name": "Sample",
  "description": "Sample demonstration",
  "version": "0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "16.0.884",
  "permissions": [
    "experimental", "tabs","<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

my popup.html's code is

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='popup.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.post('http://localhost/LinkBook/index.php', {}, function(res){
                       console.log('res');
                    });   
    });
```

But its not working. Help me out.

Comment: search for and find the Hello World sample of Chrome Extension from  http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html html file must contain html tags

Comment: maybe you meant you have popup.html which refers to popup.js. In that case try it with a valid URL. If it works the porblem is in your php server.

Comment: At-first I only put the script part of the popup html . Now I edited and put the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a sample skeleton for all post requests which is well tested and working for years; You can use it as a reference and correct your code

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "Sample",
  "description": "Sample demonstration",
  "version": "0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "16.0.884",
  "permissions": [
    "experimental", "tabs","<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.jpg",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='transaction.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***popup.js***

```
function searchquotes(){

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(data) {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log("Response is recieved");
        }
      } else {
        //callback(null);
      }
    }

var url = 'https://'+'somedomain.com/sompage.php';
xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.send();

}
window.onload = searchquotes;
```

**jquery Version**

IMP: You can not have `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>` in your code, download jquery and put it relative to your root folder, for more info check [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)(https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

***manifest.json***

```
{
  "name": "Sample",
  "description": "Sample demonstration",
  "version": "0.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "16.0.884",
  "permissions": [
    "experimental", "tabs","<all_urls>"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.jpg",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script src='transaction.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***transaction.js***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $.post("http://somedomain.com/sompage.php', {}, function(res){
                       console.log(res);
                    });   
    });
```

Comment: I was preferring jquery script because it is easier to understand for me.

Comment: @DiptopolDam: I have added my comments now you are good to go, use this skeleton;

Comment: @DiptopolDam: Have you built on skeleton i have sent? i.e removed all local script, global invocations etc?

Comment: @DiptopolDam: Can you edit your question and put all your latest edited code after suggestions there,i will debug it.

Comment: worked for me.. try changing `<script src='popup.js'></script>
<script src='jquery.js'></script>` to `<script src='jquery.js'></script><script src='popup.js'></script>`

Comment: try $.get() instead $.post()

Comment: @DiptopolDam : Post your final code after all editings, will pick from there

Comment: Finally the problem is solved.I don't know where is the problem. I again start from the scratch and this time it is working. :D thanks a lot guys for helping me out.